# Trouble getting function to work when page loads

Tags: jquery

I have the following Javascript function:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name=\"html5Alert\"]').on('change', function() {
          $('.html5Alert-fields').toggle(+this.value === 1 && this.checked);
        }).change();
    }
</script>
```

It shows or hides a DIV based on radio buttons. "ON" shows the DIV, and "OFF" hides it. As I toggle the radio buttons, the script works. It shows or hides the DIV based on which radio button is selected.

I also have the value of the radio buttons set based on values from a database.

However, it doesn't work quite right.

The Javascript needs to detect the value of the radio buttons when the page loads, and show/hide the DIV based on those values. Currently it works based on manually changing the radio buttons, but it doesn't show the correct state on page load.

How can I get that code above to run after the page loads?

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of your document.ready block and you don't need the ```\``` to escape the double quotes in the selector. Aside from that, what you have should work fine as you raise a `change()` event on load. Check the console for errors

Comment: ANd you no need to escape your double quotes, because you using single quote as string delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Close off your document.ready function.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=\"html5Alert\"]').on('change', function() {
      $('.html5Alert-fields').toggle(+this.value === 1 && this.checked);
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

Comment: The script runs twice on each page load. It shows the hidden DIV, then hides it again, regardless of which option is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also run our toggle outside of onchange event

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with a different method, which is working fine.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#html5Alert1').is(':checked')) {
        $('.html5Alert-fields').show();
    } else {
        $('.html5Alert-fields').hide();
    }

    $('input[name=\"html5Alert\"]').on('change', function() {
        if ($('#html5Alert1').is(':checked')) {
            $('.html5Alert-fields').show();
        } else {
            $('.html5Alert-fields').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```